# Excluding characters in Regex non-character class

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am trying to remove all the non-word character in a string, but want to keep punctuation mark, is there a way I can form the regex to do it (in C# 4.0)?

I tried to Google but most of the information I get is about look forward or behind. I also try something like [\W(?^,)] but this is the look forward and if I do [(?=^,)] it will simply meet any characters in (?,=,^ and ,).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search for anything that is ^NOT [a word \w  or a question mark ?]

```
[^\w?]
```

instead of NOT A WORD (\W) except question mark ?

Comment: To be precise, `[^...]` is called a complemented character class, or negated character class.